# Why is my Power Automate Parse JSON action output reading as Null instead of as an array?

Tags: json, httprequest, power-automate

I am working on a flow to delete versions from excel files in my SharePoint library based on [this reference](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Flow-Deleting-old-Versions-on-Sharepoint/td-p/350320).

I've run into a problem where an Apply to Each step won't read the outputs of a Parse JSON step as an array, although those outputs **look** fine. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

**Editor**

[image: Context steps earlier in flow]

Including this just to give you an idea of the lead-up steps. I have it filtered down to one Excel file for testing purposes, although the filter will be a permanent fixture, just with fewer limits on the items retrieved.

[image: First Send HTTP action]

Expressions here:

```
URI: _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('{PATH}')/Files('{FilenameWithExtension}')/Versions
Path: @{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{Path}']}
Filename: @{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']}
```

[image: Parse JSON step]

I can edit the schema in if needed, but it's so long and I do plan to include the outputs from the flow run below, so I'm going to skip it for now. I've tried the schema from the linked reference, and also generating from a sample of what the Send HTTP step outputs, and it changed nothing.

[image: Testing Compose step]

I inserted this Compose step to test the bits in the next step. Expressions:

```
@{body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['d']?['properties']?['results']}
@{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{Path}']}
@{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']}
@{body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['d']?['properties']?['results']?['items']?['properties']?['ID']}
```

[image: The troublesome Apply to each action]

This is the one giving me trouble when the flow runs. (I'll show that below.) Expressions:

```
@{body('Parse_JSON')?['properties']?['d']?['properties']?['results']}

Path: @{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{Path}']}
Filename: @{items('Get_versions_internal')?['{FilenameWithExtension}']}
ID: items('Clear_versions_internal')?['items']?['properties']?['ID']
```

**Flow Run**

[image: First Send HTTP]

This one runs fine.

```
URI: _api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Internal/CT/zArchive/Older/')/Files('VR Sign-in Sheet.xlsx')/Versions
```

Body:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion577e4298-b42d-4db0-8780-a484d911db2f",
          "uri": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion577e4298-b42d-4db0-8780-a484d911db2f",
          "type": "SP.FileVersion"
        },
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion577e4298-b42d-4db0-8780-a484d911db2f/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CheckInComment": "",
        "Created": "2023-04-12T00:12:39Z",
        "ID": 512,
        "IsCurrentVersion": false,
        "Length": "20696",
        "Size": 20696,
        "Url": "_vti_history/512/Internal/CT/zArchive/Older/VR Sign-in Sheet.xlsx",
        "VersionLabel": "1.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Parse JSON run 1]
[image: Parse JSON run 2]

Here are the Parse JSON outputs:

```
{
  "d": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion13655235-0e65-421f-be0c-c3bdd562c0f3",
          "uri": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion13655235-0e65-421f-be0c-c3bdd562c0f3",
          "type": "SP.FileVersion"
        },
        "CreatedBy": {
          "__deferred": {
            "uri": "https://SHAREPOINT_URL/_api/SP.FileVersion13655235-0e65-421f-be0c-c3bdd562c0f3/CreatedBy"
          }
        },
        "CheckInComment": "",
        "Created": "2023-04-12T00:12:39Z",
        "ID": 512,
        "IsCurrentVersion": false,
        "Length": "20696",
        "Size": 20696,
        "Url": "_vti_history/512/Internal/CT/zArchive/Older/VR Sign-in Sheet.xlsx",
        "VersionLabel": "1.0"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Compose run]

The results of the compose step show that it also didn't see the "results" array, but I'm not sure why.

Finally, the failed Apply to each:

[image: Offending step]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have added a property called properties twice to your expression, which I don't see in your Parse Json outputs.

Try the below instead:

```
body('Parse_Json')?['d']?['results']
```

Comment: Oh wow, thanks! I feel silly for missing that :)